# Using GROUP BY for the ChatterMessages SOBJECT

Tags: soql

hey guys i'm trying to avoid nesting my query as such

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT

            Body,
            CreatedBy.Name,
            CreatedBy.Email,
            CreatedBy.SmallPhotoUrl,
            SenderId,
            SentDate

        FROM ChatterMessages

        WHERE SentDate > 2013-04-02T00:04:11.000Z

        ORDER BY SentDate ASC

    )

FROM ChatterConversation
```

By using `group by` for the `ChatterMessage` SOBJECT like this,

```
SELECT

    Body,
    CreatedBy.Name,
    CreatedBy.Email,
    CreatedBy.SmallPhotoUrl,
    SenderId,
    SentDate

FROM ChatterMessage

WHERE SentDate > 2013-04-02T00:04:11.000Z

GROUP BY ConversationId

ORDER BY SentDate ASC
```

Unfortunetly I'm getting the dreaded `MALFORMED_QUERY: Ordered field must be grouped or aggregated: SentDate` i've tried aggregating with using `GROUP BY Id, ConversationId` but it doesn't seem to work, anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
        WHERE SentDate > 2013-04-02T00:04:11.000Z

        ORDER BY SentDate ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your 2nd query is that you're not selecting the same relationships between child and parent objects as you were in the original query! You have NO choice but to nest the query to get the same results.

To be a bit more specific as to why your 2nd query isn't working at all, you can't GroupBy the ConversationId if you haven't queried that field. I hope that helps make more sense of what's happening.

That being said, you can still do a GroupBy or OrderBy on your original query to organize the results in whatever manner suits your preferences, provided you're grouping by fields you've queried.